# How to check if there is data in JSON object in AJAX call

Tags: php, jquery

I am not able to check if the JSON data given by my PHP page has data in it or if it is empty. I have the following AJAX call. In this I want to check if the JSON data returned by my PHP page has data or not.

I am using `if (!$.trim(data))` but it is not working. Am I doing something wrong?

```js
$.ajax({
  type: "post",
  url: "../web/cpnoselected.php",
  dataType: "text",
  data: {
    'cpno': value
  },
  success: function(data) {
    if (!$.trim(data)) {
      alert("No Data Found");
    } else {
      document.getElementById("cpno").innerHTML = value;
      $("#jobdetailform").submit();
    }
  },
  error: function(jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log(errorThrown);
    console.log(jqXhr);
    console.log(textStatus);
  }
```

Comment: Note that you're returning text, not JSON, however what you have should work if you're returning `''`. Have you checked the actual responseText of the request in the network tab of dev tools?

Comment: If the returned data is an empty JSON result (i.e. `{}`) then `$.trim(data)` will not return the result you were expecting...

Comment: @rory Iam not getting any alert when there is no data in JSON result and the form is getting submited.

Comment: Avnish that's not what you were asked. Read Rory's comment again. Did you check your Network log as requested? Do you understand how to use the Developer Tools in your browser (which the network log is part of) to debug your code?